# How to create a Paypal Buy Now button for a mobile checkout from a mobile website?

Tags: paypal

I have a mobile web page with a Paypal Buy Now button and I want it to send users to a mobile friendly Paypal checkout. I'm getting really confused with documentation about for checkouts in mobile apps, but all I want is a mobile browser checkout. Can I just add an extra param to a buy now button? I've been looking at this but I think perhaps this is for mobile apps. http://code.google.com/p/paypalmobile/

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="xxxxxxxxxxx">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal — The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: Find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087146/using-paypal-express-checkout-from-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I've not found a way to use a Buy It Now button but have managed to get it working by utilising the Paypal SetExpressCheckout method in the Express Checkout API (https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp). This returns a Token which you use to redirect to Paypal

https://www.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=RETURNED_TOKEN

If you use Express Checkout Paypal automatically uses mobile checked when accessed by a mobile.

https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_ExpressCheckout_IntegrationGuide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

for mobile billing please change the url  with cmd hidden

header('location:https://mobile.paypal.com/wc?t='.$querystring);

it is device recognize URL when u are open in dektop it differnt look and mobile showing like express checkout on top showing it's amount

Comment: where is this documented?