# using paypal express checkout from jquery

Tags: jquery, paypal

I am using applicationcraft.com (based on jquery) to produce a mobile web site formatted to suite mobile device.
I can use an HTML widget that contains HTML code. (eg to produce a buy now button).
I need to add paypal express.
I am creating a shopping cart by building an array of selected items.
I now need to create a buy now button that will pass the items and total to paypal express.
The simplest solution seems to be adding buy now buttons.
I can produce some buy now buttons on the paypal site but these seem to be pre-populated with amounts.
So is it possible to create a buy now button that will just have my total amount and a description of 'computer parts'.

My code for the created button is

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="EBQ3TMYEHZU9S">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

MrWarby

Comment: You could use javascript to update the paypal buy now button values.  I did exactly that on quizzyrascal.co.uk/create-your-quiz/... Once the user has selected each of the options, I used js to get the values, and then update the paypal hidden input values

Comment: I have added my code for the created button above. There is no hidden values for the amount.

Comment: removed commented in wrong box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the "advanced" code.

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" id="business" value="me@mybusiness.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" id="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" id="item_name"  value="Teddy Bear">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" id="amount" value="12.99">
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif"     border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

Refer to this for further info: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_xclick_techview_outside

Then just manipulate input values using $('#item_name').val("");

Comment: Got that working thanks. You saved me hours of trawling looking for something quite simple. I had to use     app.w("HTML").base().find('#item_name').val('Big Computer');
    app.w("HTML").base().find('#amount').val('120'); in applicationcraft to manipulate the code in the HTML widget.

Comment: It is better to use your PayPal account ID for 'business' instead of your email.

Comment: You can also use this as a link: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=YOURpaypalID&currency_code=USD&item_name=TeddyBear&amount=12.99